# Processing files with headers in Hadoop

Tags: hadoop

I want to process a lot of files in Hadoop -- each file has some header information, followed by a lot of records, each stored in a fixed number of bytes.  Any suggestions on that?

Answer (score 4):

I think the best solution is to write a custom [`InputFormat`](http://hadoop.apache.org/core/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/InputFormat.html).

Answer (score 1):

There is one solution , you can check the offset of line of files that mapper reads . 
It will be zero for the first line in the file . so you can add line in Map as follows:

public void map(LongWritable key,Text value,Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException
        {

```
        if(key.get() > 0)
                       {
                         your mapper code
                       }
              }
```

So, it will skip the first line of the file.

However, its not a good way because in this way this condition will be checked for each line in  the file.

Best way is to use your Custom Input Format

Answer (score 0):

In addition to write a custom FileInputFormat, you will also want to make sure that the file is not splitable so the reader knows how to process the records inside the file.