# How to skip more then one lines of header in RDD in Spark

Tags: python, apache-spark

Data in my first RDD is like

```
1253
545553
12344896
1 2 1
1 43 2
1 46 1
1 53 2
```

Now the first 3 integers are some counters that I need to broadcast.
After that all the lines have the same format like

```
1 2 1
1 43 2
```

I will map all those values after 3 counters to a new RDD after doing some computation with them in function.
But I'm not able to understand how to separate those first 3 values and map the rest normally.

My Python code is like this

```
documents = sc.textFile("file.txt").map(lambda line: line.split(" "))

final_doc = documents.map(lambda x: (int(x[0]), function1(int(x[1]), int(x[2])))).reduceByKey(lambda x, y: x + " " + y)
```

It works only when first 3 values are not in the text file but with them it gives error.

I don't want to skip those first 3 values, but store them in 3 broadcast variables and then pass the remaining dataset in map function.

And yes the text file has to be in that format only. I cannot remove those 3 values/counters

Function1 is just doing some computation and returning the values.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip header from csv files in Spark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854919/how-to-skip-header-from-csv-files-in-spark)

Comment: But I don't want to skip, I want to store those 3 values in 3 different variables and then work with all other data in dataset. I don't want to pass those 3 values to the map function I described above.

Comment: Load data: `raw = sc.textFile("file.txt")`, Take first three lines you want to use for broadcast: `header = raw.take(3)`, use one of the methods described in the linked answer to skip header and process the rest.

Comment: Yeah that is correct . I'll try that, thanks..

Comment: I tried it. but since header contains 3 values so its not working. The methods in the linked answer do not deal with more then one values.

Comment: sorry My bad it worked.....

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Imports for Python 2

   ```
   from __future__ import print_function
   ```
2. Prepare dummy data:

   ```py
   s = "1253\n545553\n12344896\n1 2 1\n1 43 2\n1 46 1\n1 53 2"
   with open("file.txt", "w") as fw: fw.write(s)
   ```
3. Read raw input:

   ```py
   raw = sc.textFile("file.txt")
   ```
4. Extract header:

   ```
   header = raw.take(3)
   print(header)
   ### [u'1253', u'545553', u'12344896']
   ```
5. Filter lines:

   - using [`zipWithIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27856320/1560062)

     ```
     content = raw.zipWithIndex().filter(lambda kv: kv[1] > 2).keys()
     print(content.first())
     ## 1 2 1
     ```
   - using [`mapPartitionsWithIndex`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27857878/1560062)

     ```py
     from itertools import islice

     content = raw.mapPartitionsWithIndex(
         lambda i, iter: islice(iter, 3, None) if i == 0 else iter)

     print(content.first())
     ## 1 2 1
     ```

**NOTE**: All credit goes to [pzecevic](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1699432/pzecevic) and [Sean Owen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/64174/sean-owen) (see linked sources).

Comment: Thank you zero323 for this solution also.

Comment: So out of 3 solutions , which one is the most effecient. </br>

1. zipWithIndex

2. mapPartitonsWithIndex

3. and filter

Comment: I would go with `mapPartitionsWithIndex`.

Answer (score 3):

In my case I have a csv file like below

```
----- HEADER START -----
We love to generate headers
#who needs comment char?
----- HEADER END -----

colName1,colName2,...,colNameN
val__1.1,val__1.2,...,val__1.N
```

Took me a day to figure out

```scala
val rdd = spark.read.textFile(pathToFile)  .rdd
  .zipWithIndex() // get tuples (line, Index)
  .filter({case (line, index) => index > numberOfLinesToSkip})
  .map({case (line, index) => l}) //get rid of index
val ds = spark.createDataset(rdd) //convert rdd to dataset
val df=spark.read.option("inferSchema", "true").option("header", "true").csv(ds) //parse csv
```

Sorry code in scala, however can be easily converted to python

Answer (score 0):

First take the values using take() method as zero323 suggested

```
raw  = sc.textfile("file.txt")
headers = raw.take(3)
```

Then

```
final_raw = raw.filter(lambda x: x != headers)
```

and done.