# PySpark- How to filter row from this dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read the first row from a file and then filter that from the dataframe.

I am using `take(1)` to read the first row. I then want to filter this from the dataframe (it could appear multiple times within the dataset).

```
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql.session import SparkSession

sc = SparkContext(appName = "solution01")
spark = SparkSession(sc)

df1 = spark.read.csv("/Users/abc/test.csv")
header = df1.take(1)
print(header)

final_df = df1.filter(lambda x: x != header)
final_df.show()
```

However I get the following error `TypeError: condition should be string or Column`.

I was trying to follow the answer from Nicky here [How to skip more then one lines of header in RDD in Spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32877326/how-to-skip-more-then-one-lines-of-header-in-rdd-in-spark)

The data looks like (but will have multiple columns that i need to do the same for):

```
customer_id
1
2
3
customer_id
4
customer_id
5
```

I want the result as:

```
1
2
3
4
5
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**`take`** on **dataframe** results `list(Row)` we need to get the value use [0][0] and
In **`filter`** clause use **column_name** and filter the rows which are `not equal` to **`header`**

```
header = df1.take(1)[0][0]
#filter out rows that are not equal to header
final_df = df1.filter(col("<col_name>") != header)
final_df.show()
```