# how to remove the error : NumberFormatException.java:65 ? when we implement the code of classification in apache-spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, classification, rdd, apache-spark-mllib

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext._
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.LogisticRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.SVMWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.classification.NaiveBayes
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.DecisionTree
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.configuration.Algo
import org.apache.spark.mllib.tree.impurity.Entropy

object ScalaApp {
def main(args: Array[String]) {

   object ScalaApp {
   def main(args: Array[String]) {
   val conf = new SparkConf().setMaster("local").setAppName("Program")
   val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

   val rawData = sc.textFile("/home/sangeen/Kaggle/train.tsv")
   val records = rawData.map(line => line.split("\t"))
   records.first
   println(records.first)


/*
we will have to do a bit of data cleaning during
our initial processing by trimming out the extra quotation characters ("). There are
also missing values in the dataset; they are denoted by the "?" character. In this case,
we will simply assign a zero value to these missing values:
*/

val data = records.map { r => val trimmed = r.map (_.replaceAll("/"", ""))
val label = trimmed(r.size - 1).toInt
val features = trimmed.slice(4, r.size -1).map(d => if (d == "?")) 0.0 else d.toDouble)
LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(features))}




/*
    In the preceding code, we extracted the label variable from the last column and an
array of features for columns 5 to 25 after cleaning and dealing with missing values.
We converted the label to an Int value and the features to an Array[Double].
Finally, we wrapped the label and features in a LabeledPoint instance, converting
the features into an MLlib Vector.
We will also cache the data and count the number of data points:

You will see that the value of numData is 7395.
*/

 data.cache
 val numData = data.count

 println("value of numData is : " + numData)

/*
We will explore the dataset in more detail a little later, but we will tell you now
that there are some negative feature values in the numeric data. As we saw earlier,
the naïve Bayes model requires non-negative features and will throw an error if it
encounters negative values. So, for now, we will create a version of our input feature
vectors for the naïve Bayes model by setting any negative feature values to zero:
*/

  val nbData = records.map { r =>
  val trimmed = r.map(_.replaceAll("\"", ""))
  val label = trimmed(r.size - 1).toInt
  val features = trimmed.slice(4, r.size - 1).map(d => if (d == "?") 0.0  else d.toDouble).map(d => if (d < 0) 0.0 else d)
  LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(features))}

  val numIterations = 10
  val maxTreeDepth = 5

//Now, train each model in turn. First, we will train logistic regression:


 val lrModel = LogisticRegressionWithSGD.train(data, numIterations)

 }
 }
```

The code gives me erros :

```
  [error] (run-main-1) org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to  stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 1 times, most recent failure: Lost  task 0.0 in stage 2.0 (TID 2, localhost): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:  ",urlid,boilerplate,alchemy_category,alchemy_category_score,avglinksize,commonlinkratio_1,commonlinkratio_2,commonlinkratio_3,commonlinkratio_4,compression_ratio,embed_ratio,framebased,frameTagRatio,hasDomainLink,html_ratio,image_ratio,is_news,lengthyLinkDomain,linkwordscore,news_front_page,non_markup_alphanum_characters,numberOfLinks,numwords_in_url,parametrizedLinkRatio,spelling_errors_ratio,label"
  [error]   at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
  [error]   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:481)
  [error]   at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:527)
  [error]   at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toInt(StringLike.scala:272)
  [error]   at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toInt(StringOps.scala:30)
  [error]   at ScalaApp$$anonfun$4.apply(Program.scala:29)
  [error]   at ScalaApp$$anonfun$4.apply(Program.scala:27)
  [error]   at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:370)
  [error]   at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:278)
  [error]   at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
  [error]   at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
  [error]   at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:262)
  [error]   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
  [error]   at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:88)
  [error]   at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
  [error]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
  [error]   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
  [error]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
  [error] Driver stacktrace
  [error] (compile:run) Nonzero exit code: 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Your code is trying to convert the header columns into numbers, which are not numbers of-course. Just skip the first line and you are good to go:

```
val lst = List(1,2,3,4)
val records = sc.parallelize(lst).zipWithIndex.filter(_._2 > 0).map(_._1)
val records.collect() // Array[Int] = Array(2, 3, 4)
```

Or don't read the header line at all.

For more: [How do I skip a header from CSV files in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854919/how-to-skip-header-from-csv-files-in-spark)

Answer (score 1):

just before running the code first remove the header by the help of these steps

1) open terminal

```
Ctr + alt + t
```

2) go to the file directory

```
cd /home/sangeen/Programs/Classification
```

3) just run that one line code :

```
sed 1d train.tsv > train_noheader.tsv
```

so in directry a non-header tsv file will generate .

use the "train-noheader.tsv" file instead of "train.tsv".

for Example :

```
   val rawData = sc.textFile("/home/sangeen/Kaggle/train.tsv")
```

will become

```
    val rawData = sc.textFile("/home/sangeen/Kaggle/train-noheader.tsv")
```

Answer (score 0):

Tuxdna is correct that header is the problem but the method provided by me to filter out the header will reduce the space and time complexity of the code.

```
val data = records.filter(_.contains("urlid,boilerplate,alchemy_category")).map { r => val trimmed = r.map (_.replaceAll("/"", ""))
val label = trimmed(r.size - 1).toInt
val features = trimmed.slice(4, r.size -1).map(d => if (d == "?")) 0.0 else d.toDouble)
LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(features))}
```

---

```
val nbData = records.filter(_.contains("urlid,boilerplate,alchemy_category"))..map { r =>
val trimmed = r.map(_.replaceAll("\"", ""))
val label = trimmed(r.size - 1).toInt
val features = trimmed.slice(4, r.size - 1).map(d => if (d == "?") 0.0  else d.toDouble).map(d => if (d < 0) 0.0 else d)
LabeledPoint(label, Vectors.dense(features))}
```