# Partition rdd from text file while preserving header

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pipe, rdd

For

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file.txt")
```

where `file.txt` includes

```
Some Informative Header
value1, value11
value2, value22
```

how to partition the `rdd` into

```
Some Informative Header
value1, value11
```

and

```
Some Informative Header
value2, value22
```

so that I can run `rdd.pipe("/bin/awesomeApp")` on each partition?

**Note** Eventually my `awesomeApp` needs as the very first entry the `Some Informative Header`, the rest of entries may be computed in parallel.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip header from csv files in Spark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854919/how-to-skip-header-from-csv-files-in-spark) (Although that question doesn't explicitly ask about preserving the header, some of the answers address that detail)

Comment: If I may ask @DNA which one ? At least provide the OP with the direct link to that answer.

Comment: @eliasah Sure - [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31202898/699224) shows a way to preserve the header

Comment: I believe the OP is asking on partitioning the main file into smaller files with header for each.

Comment: @echo: is your question on how to divide an RDD into multiple RDDs or repartition the elements of an RDD into different partitions based on content?

Comment: Many Thanks for the question, whichever approach eventually my `awesomeApp` needs as a very first entry the `Some Informative Header`. The rest of the contents may be run in parallel with no dependence from each other.

Answer (score 0):

The way you want it exactly requires implementation of custom RDD and Partitions, which is not the easiest task. So, if you are agile in choice of  output format, you can convert input RDD into key-value one, where key of each row is header:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile("file.txt")
val header = rdd.take(1)
val lines = rdd.drop(1)
val headerRdd = sc.parralelize(0 to lines.count())
headerRdd.zip(lines)
```