# How do I ignore first element in Groupby in Scala /Spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I am using Spark2, Zeppelin and Scala to show the top 10 occurrences of words in a data set.
My code:

```
z.show(dfFlat.groupBy("value").count().sort(desc("count")), 10)
```

gives:
[image]
How do I ignore 'cat' and have the plot start from 'hat' i.e. show 2nd through last elements?

I tried:

```
z.show(dfFlat.groupBy("value").count().sort(desc("count")).slice(2,4), 10)
```

but this gives:

```
error: value slice is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row]
```

Comment: Tried filtering ?

Comment: Can you elaborate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's not straight forward to drop the first row in a dataframe (see also [Drop first row of Spark DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38337660/drop-first-row-of-spark-dataframe)). But you can do it using window-functions:

```
val df = Seq(
  "cat", "cat", "cat", "hat", "hat", "bat"
).toDF("value")


val dfGrouped = df
  .groupBy($"value").count()
  .sort($"count".desc)

dfGrouped.show()

+-----+-----+
|value|count|
+-----+-----+
|  cat|    3|
|  hat|    2|
|  bat|    1|
+-----+-----+

val dfWithoutFirstRow = dfGrouped
  .withColumn("rank", dense_rank().over(Window.partitionBy().orderBy($"count".desc)))
  .where($"rank" =!= 1).drop($"rank") // this filters "cat"
  .sort($"count".desc)


dfWithoutFirstRow
  .show()

+-----+-----+
|value|count|
+-----+-----+
|  hat|    2|
|  bat|    1|
+-----+-----+
```

Comment: Thanks but it gives all rows still.

Comment: See my updated answer, i think the ordering of the window was wrong

Comment: Thanks but still the same :(

Comment: @schoon this solution does work, see my self-contained example code

Comment: Yes today it does! I have a lot of problems with Zeppelin or maybe I am just an idiot. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First row can be removed in such way:

```
val filteredValue = dfGrouped.first.get(0)
val result = dfGrouped.filter(s"value!='$filteredValue'")
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the problem, it doesn't explain why or how it answers the question. Please include an explanation for your code, as that really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion