# How to split CSV lines into tuples with Spark Scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Here is a data I want to retrieve by Scala.
The data looks like this:
    userId,movieId
1,1172
1,1405
1,2193
1,2968
2,52
2,144
2,248

First I want to skip the first line, and then split user and movie by split(",") and map to (userID,movieID)

This is my first time trying scala, everything made me insane.
I wrote this code to skip first line and split

```
rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex{ (idx, iter) => 
if (idx == 0) 
    iter.drop(1) 
else     
    iter }.flatMap(line=>line.split(","))
```

But the result is something like this:

```
    1
    1172
    1
    1405
    1
    2193
    1
    2968
    2
    52
```

I guess it's because mapPartitionsWithIndex
Is there any way to correctly skip the header without change the structure?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to skip header from csv files in Spark?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854919/how-to-skip-header-from-csv-files-in-spark)

Comment: I use the same way as it, but what I want is generating (userid, movieid)

Comment: This question is quite misleading. It is actually about the `flatMap` part. A better title would be "How to split CSV lines into tuples with Spark Scala".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, your question is not about the header, but about how to split the lines into (userid, movieid)? Instead of `.flatMap(line=>line.split(","))` you should try this:

```
.map(line => line.split(",") match { case Array(userid, movieid) => (userid, movieid) })
```