# RDD skip headers - Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, rdd

I want to read an RDD with header. I found similar question here, but it's not working for me. [How do I skip a header from CSV files in Spark?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854919/how-do-i-skip-a-header-from-csv-files-in-spark)

```
rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex { (idx, iter) => if (idx == 0) iter.drop(1)
```

else iter }

so I tried

```
def f(idx, iter): 
    if idx==0:
        iter.drop(1)
    else:
        yield list(iterator)
rdd2 = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(f)
```

but it says AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'drop'

any help?

Comment: Found simple way by collecting header and filtering out, but I want to learn more about how mapPartitions work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
def f(idx, iter):
    output=[]
    for sublist in iter:
        output.append(sublist)
    if idx>0:
        return(output)
    else:
        return(output[1:])
```