# How to remove header by using filter function in spark?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I want to remove header from a file. But, since the file will be split into partitions, I can't just drop the first item. So I was using a filter function to figure it out and here below is the code I am using :

```
val noHeaderRDD = baseRDD.filter(line=>!line.contains("REPORTDATETIME"));
```

and the error I am getting says "error not found value line "what could be the issue here with this code?

Comment: Did you check this question? If yes, how is yours different?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854919/how-do-i-skip-a-header-from-csv-files-in-spark

Comment: Yes, I did. Actually, My header is not a standard schema it is just another row but the fields define the different category .

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your explanation. Would you care reviewing that please ? Add an example with some input and expected output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think anybody answered the obvious, whereby **line.contains** also possible:

```
val noHeaderRDD = baseRDD.filter(line => !(line contains("REPORTDATETIME")))
```

You were nearly there, just a syntax issue, but that is significant of course!

Answer (score 0):

Using `textFile` as below:

```
val rdd = sc.textFile(<<path>>)
rdd.filter(x => !x.startsWith(<<"Header Text">>))
```

Or

In Spark 2.0:

```
spark.read.option("header","true").csv("filePath")
```

Comment: what if I already loaded the data from the file and created an RDD and now want to create another RDD where I take a part of data and remove the header from it?

Comment: Provide your sample input file and expected output

Comment: Your last option  with spark.read as stated will have some side effects that you do not mention