# Table in Pyspark shows headers from CSV File

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a csv file with contents as below which has a header in the 1st line .

```
id,name
1234,Rodney
8984,catherine
```

Now I was able create a table in hive to skip header and read the data appropriately.
**Table in Hive**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE table_id(
  `tmp_id` string, 
  `tmp_name` string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe' 
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ( 
  'field.delim'=',', 
  'serialization.format'=',') 
STORED AS INPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat' 
OUTPUTFORMAT 
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'
LOCATION  's3://some-testing/test/data/'
tblproperties ("skip.header.line.count"="1");
```

**Results in Hive**

```
select * from table_id;
OK
1234    Rodney
8984    catherine
Time taken: 1.219 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)
```

But, when I use the same table in pyspark (Ran the same query) I see even the headers from file in pyspark results as below.

```
>>> spark.sql("select * from table_id").show(10,False)
+------+---------+                                                              
|tmp_id|tmp_name |
+------+---------+
|id    |name     |
|1234  |Rodney   |
|8984  |catherine|
+------+---------+
```

Now, how can I ignore these showing up in the results in pyspark.
I'm aware that we can read the csv file and add .option("header",True) to achieve this but, I wanna know if there's a way to do something similar in pyspark while querying tables.

Can someone suggest me a way.... Thanks   in Advance !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u can use below two properties:
**serdies properties** and **table properties**, you will be able to access table from hive and spark by skipping header in both env.

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE `student_test_score_1`(
 student string,
 age string)
ROW FORMAT SERDE
  'org.apache.hadoop.hive.serde2.lazy.LazySimpleSerDe'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES (
  'delimiter'=',',
  'field.delim'=',',
  'header'='true',
  'skip.header.line.count'='1',
  'path'='hdfs:<path>')
  LOCATION
  'hdfs:<path>'
  TBLPROPERTIES (
  'spark.sql.sources.provider'='CSV')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is know issue in [**`Spark-11374`**](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-11374) and closed as `won't fix`.

In query you can have **where clause** to select all records except **`'id'` and `'name'`**.

```
spark.sql("select * from table_id where tmp_id <> 'id' and tmp_name <> 'name'").show(10,False)
#or
spark.sql("select * from table_id where tmp_id != 'id' and tmp_name != 'name'").show(10,False)
```

Another way would be using reading files from **HDFS** with **`.option("header","true")`**.

Comment: Thanks for the response Shu. Well I can definitely add an additional filter to the query but, I wanna avoid additional filters [where tmp_id <> 'id' and tmp_name <> 'name'] in the query.

Comment: @Bjay, Another way I can think of is Read from hive table then `convert to rdd` filter out the rows then `convert back to dataframe`. But here we are doing lot of conversions (not recommended). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27854919/how-do-i-skip-a-header-from-csv-files-in-spark

Comment: Yeah too many conversations in this approach. In case of huge volume of realtime data (~18TB) in my case, I guess it’s gonna consume quite a lot time and computation. Rather  filters mentioned above might be a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

just add options ('header'='true') in the syntax.
Exp:

```
spark.sql("create table external (order_id string, location string, item string, order_date string, quantity long) using csv options ('header'='true') location '<path>'")
```